# Emacs - suppress Completion Buffer

Tags: completion, ido

In Emacs, I don't want the *Completions* buffer to pop up, even when I press tab to autocomplete in the minibuffer and there are multiple results.
It's distracting and jarring.

How can I do this?

Even better, I would like an alternative that isn't distracting or jarring -- such as requiring one tab for autocomplete if available, but requiring two tabs to open a Completions buffer. This way, I don't get the Completions buffer when I'm expecting an autocomplete. This is what the OS X terminal does to show tab completion possibilities.

I think the cause is the minibuffer-completion-help  command, which is run automatically, described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion-Commands.html

I use ido and smex, but the problem occurs in a vanilla Emacs too.

EDIT: I found a hack to fix this. Using `M-x find-function`, I found and copied the function definition of `minibuffer-completion-help` into my `.emacs.d/init.el` file. Then, I renamed the version I copied `my-minibuffer-completion-help` and changed `(with-displayed-buffer-window *Completions*` to `'(with-displayed-buffer-window *Completions*` (putting a quote in front so it is just interpreted as a string. Finally, I overrode the call to `minibuffer-completion-help` by putting

```
(advice-add 'minibuffer-completion-help
        :override #'my-minibuffer-completion-help)
```

after the `my-minibuffer-completion-help` function in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file. There must be a better way.

EDIT 2: quoting out `(message "Making completion list...")` in `my-minibuffer-completion-help` has the added benefit of getting rid of the flicker in autocomplete that is caused by flashing another message during autocomplete. Is it possible to do this another way?

Comment: Could you paste your completion edits here? That'd be really helpful. I find the completions buffer very intrusive, but it's hard to get rid of without breaking other functionality. I just want it to do the best imitation of not existing that it can do.

Answer (score 4):

Set the variable `completion-auto-help` to `lazy`. The documentation says:

```
Non-nil means automatically provide help for invalid completion input.
If the value is t the *Completion* buffer is displayed whenever completion
is requested but cannot be done.
If the value is ‘lazy’, the *Completions* buffer is only displayed after
the second failed attempt to complete.
```